# Directly defining a non-template function in terms of a template function

Tags: c++, templates, function-templates

Can I give a specific instantiation of a template function a name, so it can be called a like a non-template function?

E.g.,

```
// some template function
template <typename T>
void foo(T t) {...}

// I would like int_foo to behave like a regular function with
// foo<int> as its implementation (obviously this doesn't compile because
// using cannot be used like this)
using int_foo = foo<int>;
```

One way is to just delegate and rely on inlining to do the rest, like:

```
void int_foo(int i) {
    foo<int>(i);
}
```

... but if there is a more direct way I'm all ears.

Comment: You can already call `foo(42)` with no template arguments, thanks to template argument deduction.  Is that good enough?

Comment: In this case no. In a header file I have a declaration `int_foo(int i)` and I'd like to implement it in terms of `foo<int>` but that function doesn't appear in the header (and I don't want to expose it). So I was looking for a way to define `int_foo` in terms of `foo<>` without exposing `foo<>`. I guess I'm about to be told to include those details in the question :) @JohnZwinck

Comment: If you don't want to expose `foo<>` in the header, just declare `int_foo()` in the header but define it in the `.cpp` file.  Right?

Comment: @JohnZwinck, yes - but I want to define `int_foo` in the cpp in terms of `foo<>` without using the delegation approach.

Comment: Define `int_foo` as a function pointer then have it point to `&foo<int>` in the .cpp file.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is not, which does not require 30 characters, but all answers do.

Comment: :-D and even comments have thresholds.

Comment: Even questions have them, but writing a longer question with filler then immediately editing it to be shorter works - maybe not for answers.